# Only one issue template is displayed on GitHub though multiple issue templates markdown files are defined

Tags: github

In GitHub, you can make templates for the issues following the documentation at https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/manually-creating-a-single-issue-template-for-your-repository

We have created multiple issue templates in the `.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/` subdirectory: `_bug_report.md`, `_feature_request.md` and `_question.md` along with a `config.yml`. Our current config.yml is derived from the example and our is:

```
blank_issues_enabled: false
contact_links:
  - name: Scholia Community Support
    url: https://github.com/WDscholia/scholia/issues
    about: Please ask and answer questions here.
```

I would then expect that three options appear on our new issues choose GitHub page (https://github.com/WDscholia/scholia/issues/new/choose).

But what happens is that only one is displayed (the `_question.md`) besides the `contact_links` option. We seem to be missing the ones from `_bug_report.md` and `_feature_request.md`.

What is wrong? The markdown files have both a `name` and `about` fields defined.

Our template directory is here https://github.com/WDscholia/scholia/tree/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE

Answer (score 0):

We have now fixed the problem. I deleted all files related to the issue templates, i.e., the markdown and config.yml files, and then used the GUI provided in the GitHub settings to create new issue templates. This procedure will create new markdown issue templates files and *not* the config.yml file, so perhaps it was the config.yml that was erroneous (I have not tested that).